# How to rollback an LVM2 snapshot

Tags: filesystem, lvm, snapshot

What's the equivalent of creating a snapshot and reverting to it later on in ZFS (which is automated and usually hassle-free) in LVM2?

I've looked at the progress of this LVM2 feature a while ago and I've seen somebody working on it but it wasn't ready at the time. I've heard that LVM2 apparently has this feature available now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lvconvert --merge`, like this:

```
lvconvert --merge /dev/vgname/snapshot-name
```

This is not quick, as this requires to revert all the cow-actions on disk. Removing a snapshot *is* near-instant.

Comment: Thanks - I've actually looked at this without waiting for the answer but thought it'd be good to have it available here for the others.